# script to delete older folder in asterisk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I need a shell script to delete file and folders.
For example asterisk create a directory "/var/spool/asteisk/monitor/$year/$month/$day "

and when the disk full (or 95%) i want to run script:

```
#!bin/bash

limite="75"
dir="/var/spool/asterisk/monitor"
mes_actual=`date +%m`
anyo_actual=`date +%Y`
ref="2";
# espacio en disco #
df -h | grep /dev/xvdb1 | sed s/%//g | awk '{print $5}' >> temp.log

temp=$( cat temp.log)

if [ $limite -le $temp ];
then
        A_BORRAR=$((10#$mes_actual-$ref))
        rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo_actual"/"$A_BORRAR"
        echo "borrado" "$A_BORRAR"

else
        echo "nada para borrar"

fi

echo "all OK"
rm -Rf temp.log
df -h | grep /dev/xvdb1 | sed s/%//g | awk '{print $5}'
```

I don't know why but my script doesn't remove the folder.
The script enters to bucle "if" but doesn't remove the folder.

I use centOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to delete a directory that is protected. Try using `sudo` to delete the dir.

**To do so, change this line:**
`rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo_actual"/"$A_BORRAR"`

**To:** `sudo rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo_actual"/"$A_BORRAR"`

**So your sript will end up looking like this:**

```
#!bin/bash

limite="75"
dir="/var/spool/asterisk/monitor"
mes_actual=`date +%m`
anyo_actual=`date +%Y`
ref="2";
# espacio en disco #
df -h | grep /dev/xvdb1 | sed s/%//g | awk '{print $5}' >> temp.log

temp=$( cat temp.log)

if [ $limite -le $temp ];
then
        A_BORRAR=$((10#$mes_actual-$ref))
        sudo rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo_actual"/"$A_BORRAR"
        echo "borrado" "$A_BORRAR"

else
        echo "nada para borrar"

fi

echo "all OK"
rm -Rf temp.log
df -h | grep /dev/xvdb1 | sed s/%//g | awk '{print $5}'
```

But there's a catch: you will have to enter the sudo password each time you run the script.

A not-so-elegant and not-so-safe solution would be to edit the sudoers file.

To do so, run `sudo visudo` and enter your username and the path to the script.

`yourUserName ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/the/script`

Answer (score 0):

the problem was when doing a mathematical operation, for example: "04-2" (month April - reference month) the result was 2 (February) month that should be deleted, but as the result was "2" and not "02" , I could not find the folder to delete and the script did not work.

the script has stayed like this:

```
#!bin/bash

limit="80"
dir="/var/spool/asterisk/monitor"
mes=`date +%m`
anyo=`date +%Y`
ref="02";

# espacio en disco #
df -h | grep /dev/xvdb1 | sed s/%//g | awk '{print $5}' >> temp.log

temp=$( cat temp.log)

if [ $limit -le $temp ]; then
        BORRAR=0;
       BORRAR=$((10#$mes-$ref))

                case $BORRAR in
                1) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                2) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                3) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                4) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                5) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                6) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                7) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                8) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                9) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                10) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                11) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                12) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                esac
else
        echo "NADA PARA BORRAR"

fi
rm -Rf temp.log
```